# Navbar missing? Some plugin is messing with my wp website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I am a beginner to wp.
Some plugin is messing with my website cant figure out which one.
I have tried deactivating them all one by one but nothing worked.

My navbar is missing.

Scrolling is not working.

Here is the [link](http://www.sparkeighteen.com) to my website.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ha-header-hide` class from the header.

```
<header class="ha-header ut-header-dark ha-header-hide" id="header-section">
```

Comment: hey thanks Aaron, Because of you my header is back but i am still facing some problems. How to know which plugin is messing with my layout?